# Parse special character encoded (escaped) XML with lxml/ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

Is there a way to instruct lxml/ElementTree to parse an XML file that is still special character encoded?

It looks like this:

```
&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;
&lt;RootElement&gt;
    &lt;DataElement&gt;data&lt;/DataElement&gt;
&lt;/RootElement&gt;
```

It came as the text node of another XML file. It's huge, so I don't want to load it entirely into memory.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this? I am also facing the same issue today.

Comment: @MansoorShaikh No, I ended up finding another way to get that without without having to deal with encoded XML in XML. If memory footprint is not an issue for you, you can always just pipe it through something like `xml.sax.saxutils.unescape()`. For me that became an issue once I tried to process the data in chunks as I received it.